# Is it possible to copy data of bind mount destination to a local source folder?

Tags: linux, docker

I have Jenkins server running inside a docker container. It has mount section like this

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "/mnt/data",
        "Destination": "/var/jenkins_home",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }
]
```

I see all the jenkins job configuration is present in `/var/jenkins_home` but even though it has source `/mnt/data`, I don't see the data there. It seems that the local source folder
has been formatted. Now I want to get the data from `/var/jenkins_home` to the source directory `/mnt/data`.
Could you please explain to me the commands to do it if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that bind mount does not work - just like you I would expect `/mnt/data` to be bound to/from the container's `/var/jenkins_home`. If the host directory was emtpy though it would be expectable that the container's mount is also empty initially.

You can use `docker cp` to copy files/folders between host and a docker container.

So for example `docker cp jenkinscontainername:/var/jenkins_home ./local_dir`.

Comment: does it copy contents recursively? because when I use this command it only seems to copy the parent folder (jenkins_home) and nothing inside it. -R doesn't work with docker cp.

Comment: Yes, that copies recursively. Did you check if your folder contains anything? `docker exec jenkinscontainername ls -als /var/jenkins_home`